# going through a text file and listing how many words start with a... b.... c.... d... etc

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import string
alice = open('alice_in_wonderland.txt')
di={}.fromkeys(string.ascii_letters,0)
for word in alice:
    di[word[0]]+=1

print di
```

I'm trying to write a program that goes through a text file and produces how many words start with the letter a.. b... c.. etc.. i'm getting an error that I have no idea what it means.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/Andy/Downloads/counting_letters.py", line 5, in
>
> di[word[0]]+=1
>
> KeyError: ' '

could someone give me an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Space is not in python's ascii letters set

Comment: is there a better letter set to use?

Comment: Your map is correct (you want upper and lower case right?). You should just be careful about how you iterate over the words such that every word starts with a letter (or else all punctuation will get you)

Comment: @Aegg It's never a good thing to change the question to some unreadable text after it's been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @JacobKrall says, doing this:

```
for line in file_handle:
```

Iterates over *lines*, not words.  If you happen to have one word per line your approach might have worked, but alas.

Try just using `collection.Counter` instead of rolling your own counter.

```
from collections import Counter
with open('myfile') as f:
    c = Counter(word[0].lower() for word in f.read().split())
```

Or, if your input file is enormous (it's not, in your case) and reading it all into memory is prohibitive, the alternate form:

```
with open('myfile') as f:
    c = Counter()
    for line in f:
        c.update(word[0].lower() for word in line.split())
```

works as well.

Comment: First off... THANK YOU! 

Alright this worked, but it seems to be listing lower case a and upper case a.. that's just one instance like that.. Is there a way to clean this up a bit? Sorry for asking so many questions.

Comment: add `.lower()` after `word[0]`.

Comment: hahaa. alright. that fixed it.. one more question i promise. lol. Its listing symbols as well. is there any way to get those out of there also?

Answer (score 1):

A `KeyError` means the key `' '` is not in your dictionary.

`word[0]` was `' '` (the SPACE character).

Are you sure that

```
for word in alice:
```

actually iterates over words?

Comment: I thought it does, but apparently I'm doing something wrong.. what is a better way to write this? sorry i'm a noob at programming. >.<